# Metadata for User Interface options

Tags: metadata-api, metadata

Does anyone know whether the User Interface option Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions can be used with Metadata?  Has anyone found a workaround?

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm

Answer (score 1):

For those that are still looking:
Retrieve the Security.Settings-meta-xml, it will hold the following setting: "enableAuditFieldsInactiveOwner"