# Scratch org with "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" enabled

Tags: salesforcedx

We wish to create a scratch org that has the "Enable "Set Audit Fields upon Record Creation" and "Update Records with Inactive Owners" User Permissions" setting checked.

Is there a scratch org definition file option available to do this that I'm not seeing.  Or failing that is there a programmatic way of setting the setting.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of [Metadata for User Interface options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/189305/metadata-for-user-interface-options) which is unanswered. Note, when you do a source:pull after enabling those Setup features, only the NameSettings is retrieved from the User Interface configuration. Github [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/797) was opened in Dec '18 but has been closed without solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What to do

I wrote out instructions in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/allisonletts/sfdx-audit-fields-sample/blob/master/README.md), including sample files if you need them.

1. In the source org

   - Run `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Settings:Security`
   - Search the retrieved file for `enableAuditFieldsInactiveOwner` and set the value to `true`. Save the file.
2. In a new scratch org

   - Run `sfdx force:source:deploy -m Settings:Security` **immediately** after creating the scratch org
   - Run `sfdx force:source:push` as usual
   - If needed, assign any needed permission sets using `sfdx force:user:permset:assign --permsetname [yourauditfieldpermset]`

---

### Why should this work?

Basically, you need to enable the `set audit fields` setting for the org **before** you attempt to add it to any permission sets or profiles. If you try to enable the setting and push the permission set at the same time, it'll fail silently--the rest of the permission set will go through, but not that piece.

Comment: Thanks Allison.  Will give this a try.  Nice thinking.

Comment: This just saved me a ton of head scratching!  Thank you

Comment: Life pro tip: you can use `packageDirectories` to stage push of your security settings and profie/permset. They are now pushed in order they are specified in `sfdx-project.json`.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure your **project-scratch-def.json** like this:

```
{
  "orgName": "Scratch", 
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [],
  "settings": {
      "securitySettings": {
        "enableAuditFieldsInactiveOwner": true
      }
  }
}
```

This will create your scratch org with this setting pre-configured so you do not need more steps.

In [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_securitysettings.htm) full documentation of security settings.